# C# memory leak by CompilerParameters.GenerateInMemory=true

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

```
static void compile()
{
    CodeNamespace cn = new CodeNamespace("System.IO.TextReader");
    CodeCompileUnit ccu = new CodeCompileUnit();
    ccu.Namespaces.Add(cn);

    CSharpCodeProvider icc = new CSharpCodeProvider(); 
    CompilerParameters cplist = new CompilerParameters();
    cplist.GenerateExecutable = false;
    cplist.GenerateInMemory = false;  //★ memory is high when true

    cplist.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
    cplist.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.XML.dll");
    cplist.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Web.Services.dll");
    cplist.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll");
    CompilerResults cr = icc.CompileAssemblyFromDom(cplist, ccu);

}
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
    {
        compile();
    }
    long usedMemory = proc.PrivateMemorySize64;
    Console.WriteLine(usedMemory);  //print the memory size
}
```

when `GenerateInMemory` is set to `true`, **the produce allocate more memory?**

***The result is:***

```
GenerateInMemory      Memory Size (byte)
 true                   21688320 
 false                  16424960
```

***My question is:***

1. the compile result in the memory will not GC by VM?
2. appdomain will not unload the assembly?

Comment: You can't prove a memory leak without at least running a full garbage collection first.

Comment: And even then you need to do a full garbage collection, wait for pending finalizers, then do a 2nd full garbage collection to truly get everything. (`GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); GC.Collect()`)

Comment: when I do 2nd full GC. the memory size would drop from 21M to 18M, Does it means that full GC has do the job?  In my project, the frequency of call the compile function is high. So! Should not do the compile job in static function.